# How to pass data from one page to another on click

Tags: php, mysql

I realize this may be a begginer's question, but upon searching around, nothing really seemed to solve my problem.

I need to send information from one page, to another page through a button. I haven't made this code, so i don't know how everything works, but what i know is that it passes information to other pages through the onclick event. I created another page that needs to get one information from this page, yet for some reason it's not working. It's sort of like this:

```
if  (!empty($_GET['short_proj_name'])){
    $strQueryInfo = "SELECT DISTINCT proj_id,pcr FROM projetos_main WHERE short_proj_name='".$_GET['short_proj_name']."'";
    $execInfo= mysql_query($strQueryInfo);
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array($execInfo)){
        $strProjId = $info['proj_id'];
        $strPCR = $info['pcr'];
    }
}else{
    $strPCR = $_POST['txtpcr'];
}
```

So this is the code that selects the "pcr" and the "short_proj_name" fields. I need to pass the "pcr" field to my other page. So here is the button that does it.

```
<input type="submit" class="submit" onclick="window.open('Test.com/main/modules/Site_teste/About.php?pcr=<?=$strPCR?>', '_blank')" value="About"/>
```

I tried using `About.php?pcr=<?=$_GET['pcr']?>` Instead of using $strPCR as well, but it didn't work also. I thought about making a form action that redirects me to this page, but i don't really know how that works, so i couldn't get it to function properly. Is there anything i'm missing? If there's information that i still have to give then please tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your button in a form tag,example :

```
<form action="your page" method="post">
   PCR: <input type="text" name="pcr">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit">
</form>
```

then in the other page, you can get the value like this :

$pcr= $_POST['pcr']

hope it works

Comment: Can you show me how to do this without the textbox? Because the PCR has already been preloaded in a previous page

Comment: how you loaded it ? via session ? or?